# Steven Johnson's DevonThink writing workflow: is creating & accumulating 50-500 word snippets worth the effort?

Tags: software, organization, research, ideas

Steven Berlin Johnson talks in [this much cited article](http://www.stevenberlinjohnson.com/movabletype/archives/000230.html) about his research workflow using DevonThink.  In short, he advocates for creating 50-500 word focused text snippets from your research readings and placing them in DevonThink for future use.  Reason: short, focused snippets allows DevonThink's "See Also" AI feature to come up with many overlooked associations between your snippets.  These associations allow you to get a much more in-depth use of your previously read research that you may have forgotten about or never made a link to on your own.

My question: **is it worth the effort?**  Is the pain of accumulating enough 50-500 word snippets in DevonThink during research worth the gain you receive from it in the writing process?  Converting previously-read articles to 50-500 word snippets can be very time consuming.  And the effort required to create a DevonThink snippet database large enough to make the "See Also" function useful is a substantial investment.

Has anyone used both Johnson’s DevonThink workflow and another database applicaton with standard search features?  Can you offer a comparison?  Are the associations and “new leads” that are uncovered using Johnson’s DevonThink 50-500 word snippet technique worth the effort?  Or will you get, for example, 80-90% of the same results just using whole articles dumped into Evernote, EagleFiler etc and relying on its built-in search functions when retrieving research ideas?  Are these two research techniques comparable or entirely different in their results?  If so, how?

Comment: One comment I've found that addresses this situation: why does splitting up longer documents help?  The answer is written [here](http://williamjturkel.net/2011/03/27/burst-documents/) by Willam J. Turkel:

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of wasting so much time doing it that way.
But it is not uncommon to write a single paragraph, and then create a series of short one or two line MRUs (Motivation Reaction Unit) lines from it.

This method is used a lot in mysteries so you do not overlook clues, or use them, or a description of something more than once.  Or to prevent redundant descriptions of a scene.

When I am compiling my research notes, I often write a list of keywords or short sentences to glance over quickly for what I'm looking for.  The programs I use now let me link the notes to the articles, so if I forget what my note meant, I can click on it and it takes me to the article.  I often have several links to the same article to cover all facets of what it contained.

VTY
Dutch